# How to find distance from scrollTop?

Tags: javascript

I did [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwutzjj1/):

```js
var outer = document.querySelectorAll('.outer');

setInterval(function() {
  // console.log(outer.scrollY); // undefined 
  // console.log(outer.scrollTop); // undefined
}, 500);
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 220px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" style="background-color:red"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color:yellow"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color:green"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color:blue"></div>
</div>
```

I need the *setInterval* to get the correct *distance from top*. But it always returns `undefined`. I've read some related questions, the only difference I found is that I'm not using `window.scrollTop`, but that is because I will not scroll the `window`, I will scroll the `.outer` element. I need to know the `outer.scrollTop`, which I'm in trouble.

Any ideas?

Comment: Won't `.querySelectorAll` return an array? You'd have to do `outer[n].scrollY` to find the `scrollY` property on a single dom element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working as expected because the [`.querySelectorAll()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of elements. You are trying to retrieve the `scrollTop` property of the collection (which obviously doesn't work). You need to retrieve the `scrollTop` property of a specific element *in* the collection.

You could access the first element in that NodeList:

```
var outer = document.querySelectorAll('.outer');

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(outer[0].scrollTop);
}, 500);
```

Or use the [`.querySelector()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead:

```
var outer = document.querySelector('.outer');

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(outer.scrollTop);
}, 500);
```